# Можно ли автоматически считывать значение checkbox?

Tags: php

Есть 3 чекбокса, нужно при нажатии на каждый из них накапливать переменную. Т.е.:

```
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH1" name="f1" VALUE="1"> Ракетка<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH2" name="f2" VALUE="2"> Кроссовки<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH3" name="f3" VALUE="3"> Теннисный мяч<BR>
```

К примеру при нажатии на 1ый чекбокс к какой-то переменной `$sum` прибавлялось какое-то число, если галочка убирается - то и число обратно вычитается. При нажатии на 2й чекбокс снова прибавлять какое-то число и также с третьим чеком. Такое возможно реализовать? Если да, то как?

Comment: Все эти input’ы и соответствующие нажатия «живут» в браузере, а не на сервере, так что нужно либо на каждое нажатие слать ajax-запрос, либо считать на стороне браузера с JavaScript.

Comment: Это неправильно. Посмотрите на свои три строки. Если будет число 3, то что это значит? Выбран теннисный мячик или ракетка + кроссовки?

Comment: Всем чекбоксам задаётся одно и тоже имя в виде `array[]` (имя массива с квадратными скобками на конце) и сервер получает список выбранных опций в массиве array[].

Comment: Ещё про сложение. Чтобы по сумме можно было однозначно установить что же было выбрано, надо чтобы value были степенями двойки. Тогда каждое value устанавливает только свой разряд в сумме и таким образом достигается однозначность. f1=1 f2=2 f4=4 f5=8 ... Сумма двух и более таких чисел никогда не совпадёт с одним из значений.